# web3js inside an HTML page

Tags: web3js

I had some ideas of small web apps. 
However, I do not want to host a web server.
Therefor, I am wondering if it is possible to integrate web3js (min, light or full) inside an  HTML page.

For example, I would have my basic web page and inside, (in script tags obviously), I would have the entire web3js code. The page should be able to do all the stuff web3 is able to do.

This page would be distributed by a google function.

**In the web3js repo, there is the dist folder with min/light version of web3js. If it is possible, how can I include this code inside an HTML page and use it? Which one would be the most suitable for this use case?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web3.js can be called as both client side or as server side code. More info at [web3.js execution - server vs browser](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11991/web3-js-execution-server-vs-browser) . Yes, you can just use it client side (in browser). You would use the min version of web3.js in this case.

Comment: I accepted the answer a bit too fast. In my case I don't want to use a web server. I plan to create a google function that will just return me an HTML file with the JS code required bundled inside the HTML file. Is that possible?